# Where can I mine copper ore in WOW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Where do I find copper ore to mine in WOW? They are too expensive at the auction house, and I can't seem to find it on any guides..

Comment: Have you actually turned on mining tracking? You shouldn't really have any trouble finding copper ore in lower level areas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best Areas for copper are the first 2 starting areas of each race, normally there is plenty to go around, but Bots and other Players can make the life of a Newbie very hard when it comes to gathering.

**Humans**

- Elwynn Forest
- Westfall

**Dwarfs**

- Dun Morogh
- Loch Modan

**Trolls & Orcs**

- Durotar
- The Barrens

**Tauren**

- Mulgore
- The Barrens

**Undead**

- Tirisfal Glades
- Silverpine Forest

**Elves**

- Teldrassil
- Moonglade

**Worgen**

- Gilneas
- Silverpine Forest

**Blood Elves**

- Eversong Woods
- Ghostland

**Draenei**

- Azuremyst Isles
- Bloodmyst Isle

Another possible solution would be to download an Addon like Gatherer, that can show you all possible spots on your minimap if so desired and if you download a [premade database](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info11707-GathererDBWoWHead.html).

Also do not forget to enable ore tracking. You find this ability in your skillbook.

Comment: Note that Gatherer doesn't come out-of-the-box with locations.  It builds them over time from the gathers of your characters and your guild-mates.  You can also download a separate library of locations, or merge from a friend's library.  And don't forget to turn on ore tracking on your mini-map.

Answer (score 12):

The two best zones to mine Copper Ore in World of Warcraft are as follows. These zones statistically result in the highest yield of Copper Ore in game.

If you're Horde, follow the highlighted path around Durotar;

[image]

If you're Alliance, follow the highlighted path around Darkshore;

[image]

Images taken from the [WoW profession guide](http://www.wow-professions.com/wowguides/wow-mining-guide.html#1), which contains details on the best route to get each different type of ore in game.

Answer (score 9):

Be sure to enable the [Find minerals](http://www.wowwiki.com/Find_Minerals) ability.

The starter zones are good places to get copper ore

**Aliance**
[Elwynn Forest](http://www.wowwiki.com/Elwynn_Forest)
[Darkshore](http://www.wowwiki.com/Darkshore)
[Dun Morogh](http://www.wowwiki.com/Dun_Morogh)
[Azuremyst Isle](http://www.wowwiki.com/Azuremyst_Isle)

**Horde**
[Durotar](http://www.wowwiki.com/Durotar)
[Mulgore](http://www.wowwiki.com/Mulgore)
[Eversong Woods](http://www.wowwiki.com/Eversong_Woods)
[Tirisfal Glades](http://www.wowwiki.com/Tirisfal_Glades)

The following guide should give you an idea of an optimal route: [Copper Ore farming](http://www.wow-professions.com/farming/copper-ore-farming)

I use an addon called [Gatherer](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/gatherer) to help easily find and keep track of the ore locations, in conjunction with the [Altoholic](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/altoholic) addon to keep track of which of my characters has a particular ore in their bags or bank

Comment: To make gatherer more useful, you can download [a premade database](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info11707-GathererDBWoWHead.html) containing all the world node locations.