# How can I level gathering professions quickly as a high-level character?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So at level 7 or 8 I picked up Mining and Smithing as professions. So after a while I kind of forgot about them. Now, a few montages later and I'm a level 62 and still have low-level mining. I guess I should go back to Brill and mine. Is their another way to level gather professions quickly?

Comment: I had the same situation with my level 90 gatherers who I boosted to 90.  Go mine nodes on Timeless Isle when you hit 90.  They are all orange to you, give you +1 skill each time you gather, and can start being gathered at profession level 1.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you to first reach level 90, ignoring your professions, because of these resaons:

- the gathering is much easier when you have a fast mount
- if you just have the profession to earn gold (for example selling ores in the auction house) there's no reason to do this with level 62 since you'll only need much gold for different stuff when you're level 90
- also, if you want to combine 2 professions (for example mining and smiting), you'll need a high amount of gold to progress in smiting and you wouldn't be able to skill it up to 600 anyway with your level.

Once you're  level 90 you should search the internet for profession leveling guides, I'm sure you'll find some good ones ;)

EDIT: 
Tiny addition that came to my mind , if you want to buy the new expansion "Warlords of Draenor" you could pre-order it now you'll receive an "Level 90 boost". If you give this boost to a level 60+ character, you'll not only be level 90, you would also get both professions leveled up to 600.
This is the fastest way to level up if you're willing to pay money.

Answer (score 3):

For Mining you can also wait until you get to pandaria. The ore deposits there do not have any (skill-)level requirement to be mined. (see http://wowhead.com/object=209311)

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to figure out what areas have what level gathering nodes and go back and get to work.

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to gather skill points quickly, it takes a while switching areas every 100 or 200 skillpoints without even having a fast mount.

Answer (score 2):

With Professions you have basically 2 major options for leveling:

- You start with level 5-10 and you just gather/craft everything that you can lay hands on
- You start with level 90 and you will invest a lot of Time or Gold

Personally I Like the first method most since Leveling is more fun when training a profession.

Anyways As you've mentioned you asked about training at higher levels and one thing you should do is buying the 280% mount. Now for Gathering professions you will have to invest a lot of time because there simply is just one way of training them: **Grinding**

I'd suggest you follow some of the well known farming patterns for different professions (German website but you should get the maps):

- [Mining](http://www.wowberufeguide.de/farmen/erze-farmen.html)
- [Herbalism](http://www.wowberufeguide.de/farmen/kraeuter-farmen.html)
- [Skinning](http://www.wowberufeguide.de/farmen/leder-farmen.html)

Another thing that really helps with these professions, not only for leveling them but also later for farming in general is the Addon [Gatherer](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/gatherer) which saves the locations of Ores,Herbs and Other stuff like Treasure chests etc.

Also just as a small tip: I suggest to keep the stuff you get from at least one of the professions so you can easily train a crafting profession afterwards. These provide a strong Boost to your main stat and they can also be used for making money.

Answer (score 1):

With the mining profession you can buy ore at the auction house and use it to level your mining skill by smelting bars.

There are certain points where this may become prohibitively expensive, so you can combine buying the ores with mining to fill in the gaps. Gold and Silver ores are quite rare but many of the other ores that you need are usually available on the auction house because people use them for crafting armour or prospecting gems.

It's usually quite obvious which ores you need to get next, because they will be rendered in an orange colour in your mining skill window.

You can find more information about mining and links to some guides the following question

[Where can I mine copper ore in WOW?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119479/where-can-i-mine-copper-ore-in-wow)

Answer (score 1):

My personal suggestion would be that you just finish leveling to 90 and then worry about leveling up your profession since it is already behind. I would also, generally, suggest not leveling a gathering profession on your 'main' character (if this character is your main/only character) but that is from a min/max perspective.

If you're still adamant about going back and leveling up your mining, gathering, or any other profession I suggestion using the guides on [this website](http://www.wow-professions.com/). They are very well written, simple, and detailed. Hope that helps :)